# Session variable lost only after time passes

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

These two pages are stripped-down versions of pages in a larger PHP application. **page1** calls a function (in the app, **f** executes SQL) which returns a two-element array, a string and an array. It then puts the array portion of the return variable into a session variable and displays a link to **page2**. **page2** assigns the session variable to a local variable. But ...

If the link is clicked immediately, all is well. If more than about 5-10 minutes (varies) pass before clicking it, the second page can't find the session variable and throws an "Undefined index" error.

This is counter-intuitive to me but maybe it's not to someone more familiar with PHP. I've tried disabling garbage collection but the results are the same. Can anyone explain why the session variable gets lost?

**page1.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function f() {
        $rtnValue = array ( 'error' => null, 'table' => array() );
        $rtnValue['error'] = '';
        $rtnValue['table'] = array('a','b','c');
        return $rtnValue;
    }
    $result = f();
    $dataTable = $result['table'];
    $_SESSION['termTable'] = $dataTable;
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="page2.php">Go to page2.php</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function customError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        echo "ERROR ", $errno, ": ", $errstr, " in ", $errfile, " at line ", $errline;
        exit();
    }
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_error_handler('customError');
    $dataTable2 = $_SESSION['termTable'];
    // Undefined index: termTable in D:\www\hr\_DEV\PHP\sessionError\page2.php at line 9
?>
<html>
    <body>
        Okay
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your session handler? If files: are you on shared hosting or on a debian based system? If memcache(d): what is the current usage of memcached, are purges taking place? If other: which? Sharing the entire `session` portion of `phpinfo();` might be wise, as it can be a lot of things.

Comment: phpinfo() returns nothing. admins have it disabled?

Comment: Nothing? It should normally just provide a full blown HTML page with all your settings... Weird. But: what does `'var_dump(ini_get_all('session'));` show us then?

Comment: Too long for a comment.  http://notepad.cc/xauxova13

Comment: OK, timeouts OK, files handler, and `D:\PHP5\SessionData` as session storage path. Questions: is that single key empty in your session, or is the entire session empty? If it is that single key: its most likely a code problem somewhere, check your access logs what other requests might run from your IP. If it's your entire session gone: are you on shared hosting, and is it possible someone defined a _lower_ session timeout, and uses the same folder for session storage, which would make his garbage handler remove your sessions. If so, try another writable directory as session storage path.

Comment: What you say is very educational. The system is shared by hundreds of people so it very well may be that resources are purged often. The rest of the session is okay, it's just this one variable that goes missing. I just need to figure out a workaround. Thanks Wrikken.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini to check how long the session is kept alive:

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 300
```

You can set it on runtime using:

session_set_cookie_params

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime') returns 0

Comment: What about session.gc_maxlifetime

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime is 2400 (40 minutes). I've also tried gc_disable with no change.

Comment: Try changing the session save path to something only you use (to rule out shared issues with other users) using: session_save_path('/home/path/local.com/tmp');